# Spring Boot - property could not be resolved in xml from application.properties

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a spring boot application

My `@Configuration class` loads the xml Configuration using `@ImportResource("path/to/xml")`, which contains the following line

```
<property name="bla" value="${log.directory}/file.ext" />
```

Under `src/main/resources` I have the `application.properties` file with the following content:

```
log.directory=C:/path/I/Need
```

However when I run It fails to load the property as follows:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'log.directory' in string value "${log.directory}/file.ext`"

Comment: Do you have a property placeholder resolver bean?

Comment: No. Shouldn't Spring Boot automatically load the application.properties?

Comment: I don't know boot very well. Are you expecting it to load all `.properties` from the classpath?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: according to part 21.2 It should load the application.properties contents

Comment: Loading properties (having them available) is different than resolving placeholders (using them). That's where I would start looking.

Comment: Adding the property-placeholder works mind you. But I don't think it's the expected behaviour. Feel free to post the answer

Comment: @mangusbrother Have you tried turning the logging level to DEBUG to see the locations where Spring is searching from the property?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can solve it adding context:property-placeholder to you xml. That way you will tell Spring to load your specific properties file.

However another more in line with Spring Boot solution is just using application.properties as the name for your properties file, having it in one of the expected locations, and use the @EnableAutoconfiguration annotation.

Spring Boot expects the application.properties in the following location in order of preference.

1. A /config subdir of the current directory.
2. The current directory
3. A classpath /config package
4. The classpath root

I have tried this and it works.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Sample</name>
    <description>Spring Boot sample</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Package as an executable jar -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Sample.java

```
package sample;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource("classpath:beans.xml")
public class Sample implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Value("${sample}")
    private String sample;

    @Autowired
    SampleService service;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Sample.class, args);
    }

    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println(service.greetings());
    }
}
```

SampleService.java

```
package sample;


public class SampleService {

    private String field;

    public String greetings() {
        return field;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="sample.SampleService">
        <property name="field" value="${sample}-world"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

application.properties

```
sample=hello
```

In the output you will get *hello world* if you run the program.

**Make sure that you have enabled the autoconfiguration. If you did not, it will not work as expected. In order to do so, add the @EnableAutoconfiguration annotation as in the example.**

Please note that you are using Spring Boot, so you are encouraged to avoid XML configuration. You can get the same result with no beans.xml at all. Although, if you still need it, you can mix XML with annotations.

I have uploaded both sample projects to GitHub, please check.

https://github.com/plopcas/example-spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-xml

https://github.com/plopcas/example-spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already had a working beans.xml configuration and just needed to execute this using spring-boot instead. The issue was that I needed to add <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>

Comment: Ok, yes, with the context:property-placeholder it equally works. And that is specially useful when your properties file is called something different than application.properties. Also, your extra attributes order="1" ignore-unresolvable="true" are useful when you have more than one properties file.

Comment: But as you can see in my GitHub project st-springboot, that is not required thanks to the convention over configuration that Spring Boot favours. But also, you can have a beans.xml, and mix annotations with xml configuration (st-springboot-xml), and Spring Boot will pick the application.properties file automatically assuming that you have enabled the autoconfiguration (@EnableAutoconfiguration). I have updated the answer to highlight that. Anyway, glad you solved the problem. If you have time, please check the projects, as I reckon this one is a more specific answer to your question. Regards.